# Hangman assignment and loop conditions

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a JAVA assignment where I have to create a `Hangman` program using arrays and loops.

- user1 inputs a valid word (no numbers or symbols)
- user2 can try to guess the whole word in one shot OR guess using one letter in a total of 10 tries. Initially, user2 had to press 1 to guess the word or 2 to choose a letter. I changed that since I think this is more user friendly.
- user2 can try to guess the word at any point in time.

The program needs to check that user2's input is valid

- Has to be an alphabet character, not a symbol
- Has to be only 1 character length OR the same length as the word to guess).
- An alphabet character cannot be used twice

If the user2's input is invalid (conditions above), it gives an error message and asks user2 to input something else. Any invalid input does not count towards the 10 tries.

For now, if the input is invalid (first 2 conditions above), the code behaves like it should. It gives an appropriate error message and the number of attempts does not increase.

However, I cannot seem to be able to code a condition where if a letter is already chosen, that it also gives an error message and asks for another letter.

I tries to put in an if condition `(if upperAlphabet[index] == '*', System.out.println("Duplicate. Try again"))` in the first do/while loop but it is not working properly: it increases the attempts count.

I have the impression I have to do a for loop somewhere. Can't find where and how.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] upperAlphabet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };  // Alphabet array to display to user2. 

    String wordtoGuess;
    char letterChoice;
    String userChoiceString;
    String wordArraytoString;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid word (letters only)");   // Asks user1 for a valid word
        Scanner wordInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        wordtoGuess = wordInput.next();
        wordtoGuess = wordtoGuess.toUpperCase();
    } while (Pattern.matches("[A-Z]+", wordtoGuess) == false);     // Checks word is valid

    char[] wordArray = wordtoGuess.toCharArray();   // Puts word in character array               
    char[] guessingWordArray = new char[wordtoGuess.length()];
    for (int h = 0; h < guessingWordArray.length; h++) 
        guessingWordArray[h] = '*'; // Displays the word to guess with * for user2

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  // Prints 20 empty lines to hide the input of the word from user1 
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {   // 10 attempts loop

        do {

            System.out.print("Word to guess: ");
            System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
            System.out
                    .println("Please choose a letter or solve the word.    " // Asks for a letter or the whole word
                            + "Attempts left: " + (10 - j));
            System.out.println(upperAlphabet);
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            userChoiceString = userInput.next();
            userChoiceString = userChoiceString.toUpperCase();    // Captures the input as a string
            letterChoice = userChoiceString.charAt(0);
            letterChoice = Character.toUpperCase(letterChoice);  // Captures the first letter of the input

            if (Character.isLetter(letterChoice) == false) // Error if input is an alphabet letter
                System.out.println("Invalid letter. Please try again.");
            if (userChoiceString.length() > 1 // Error if input is not the same length as the whole word but more than 1 character
                    && userChoiceString.length() < wordtoGuess.length())
                System.out.println(("Choose only one letter. Try again."));

        } while (userChoiceString.length() != 1
                && userChoiceString.length() != wordtoGuess.length()
                || Character.isLetter(letterChoice) == false);

        if (userChoiceString.length() == 1) { // if input is only 1 character

            for (int k = 0; k < upperAlphabet.length; k++) { // A used letter is replaced by * in alphabet array.
                if (letterChoice == upperAlphabet[k]) {
                    upperAlphabet[k] = '*';
                }
            }

            for (int m = 0; m < wordtoGuess.length(); m++) { // If a letter is correct, reveal the correct letter in the word to guess.
                if (letterChoice == wordArray[m]) {
                    guessingWordArray[m] = wordArray[m];
                }
            }
            wordArraytoString = new String(guessingWordArray); // If all letters are revealed in the word to guess, display winning message when count of guesses.
            if (wordArraytoString.equals(wordtoGuess)) {

                System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
                System.out.print("Congratulations.");
                System.out.print("You guessed the word: ");
                System.out.print(wordtoGuess);
                System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guesses.");
                break;

            }

        } else if (userChoiceString.length() == wordtoGuess.length()) { // If user2 tries to guess the whole word, displays winning message and number of guesses
            if (userChoiceString.equals(wordtoGuess)) {
                System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
                System.out.print("Congratulations.");
                System.out.print("You guessed the word: ");
                System.out.print(wordtoGuess);
                if (j == 0)
                    System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guess.");
                else
                    System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guesses.");
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Wrong guess. Please try again."); // If guessing word is wrong.
        }

        if (j >= 9)
            System.out
                    .println("You did not guess the word in the number of attemps allowed. Better luck next time."); // If exceeds 10 tries.
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What you need is some kind of data structure, such as a `HashSet`, to store the guesses that the player has already made, and a check of whether the player's guess is already in the structure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am in a beginner's class so we have not touched hashsets yet.

Comment: It looks like your way of checking whether or not the letter has already been guessed does work though. Keeping an array of characters and changing one to a certain special value (*) should work, it just isn't the most efficient way but I doubt a beginning class will care about efficiency. Check out my reply below if that's what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the array `upperAlphabet` which you're modifying when the user makes a guess.  Maybe you could arrange things so that if the guess has gone from `upperAlphabet`, the user is prompted to repeat the guess.

Why don't you move this loop

```
for (int k = 0; k < upperAlphabet.length; k++) { // A used letter is replaced by * in alphabet array.
    if (letterChoice == upperAlphabet[k]) {
        upperAlphabet[k] = '*';
    }
}
```

up a few lines into the `do/while` loop where you're prompting the user for input.  Make sure it only runs if they guess just one character.

You could then add the line `boolean found = false;` before it, and `found = true;` inside the `if` part.  Then immediately following the loop, check the value of `found`, and show a message if it's still false, which will be the case if the user repeats a guess.

You'll still need to work out a way to get the `do/while` loop to repeat if the guess is not `found`.  So this is not a complete answer, but it should be enough to get you going again.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I played with the code and I decided (maybe it's not efficient, but anyways) to create a method that will check the upperAlphabet array and see if letterChoice is still in the array. I called that method in the main code and added the condition "duplicateLetters(upperAlphabet, letterChoice) == -1" in the first do/while loop. Seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is just create another array to push your seen characters into instead of overwriting the values in upperAlphabet, this way finding it is easier and less messy.

```
ArrayList<char> guessed = new ArrayList();
....
do{
  ...
while(//your conditions here
     && !guessed.contains(letterChoice) );
guessed.add(letterChoice));
```

You can do this with regular arrays too, with something like the following.

```
char guessed = new char[10];
do{
  ...
while(//your conditions here
      &&!contains(guessed, letterChoice));
add(guessed, letterChoice)

//supporting methods
public boolean contains(char[] arr, char val){
  //check that array has value
}

public void add(char[] arr, char val){
  //add val to first empty space in arr.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to expand on David Wallace's answer, this modificiation of your code now does what you want (although it still needs the additional condition that he mentioned):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] upperAlphabet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
            'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };  // Alphabet array to display to user2. 

    int[] guessedLetters = new int[26];

    boolean guessed = false;

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        guessedLetters[i] = 0;
    }

    String wordtoGuess;
    char letterChoice;
    String userChoiceString;
    String wordArraytoString;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid word (letters only)");   // Asks user1 for a valid word
        Scanner wordInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        wordtoGuess = wordInput.next();
        wordtoGuess = wordtoGuess.toUpperCase();
    } while (Pattern.matches("[A-Z]+", wordtoGuess) == false);     // Checks word is valid

    char[] wordArray = wordtoGuess.toCharArray();   // Puts word in character array               
    char[] guessingWordArray = new char[wordtoGuess.length()];
    for (int h = 0; h < guessingWordArray.length; h++) 
        guessingWordArray[h] = '*'; // Displays the word to guess with * for user2

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  // Prints 20 empty lines to hide the input of the word from user1 
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {   // 10 attempts loop

        do {

            guessed = false;

            System.out.print("Word to guess: ");
            System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
            System.out
                    .println("Please choose a letter or solve the word.    " // Asks for a letter or the whole word
                            + "Attempts left: " + (10 - j));
            System.out.println(upperAlphabet);
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            userChoiceString = userInput.next();
            userChoiceString = userChoiceString.toUpperCase();    // Captures the input as a string
            letterChoice = userChoiceString.charAt(0);
            letterChoice = Character.toUpperCase(letterChoice);  // Captures the first letter of the input

            if (Character.isLetter(letterChoice) == false) // Error if input is an alphabet letter
                System.out.println("Invalid letter. Please try again.");
            else if (userChoiceString.length() > 1 // Error if input is not the same length as the whole word but more than 1 character
                    && userChoiceString.length() < wordtoGuess.length())
                System.out.println(("Choose only one letter. Try again."));
            for (int k = 0; k < upperAlphabet.length; k++) { // A used letter is replaced by * in alphabet array.
                if(guessedLetters[k] == 1)
                {
                    guessed = true;
                    System.out.println("You've already tried this letter. Please try again.");
                }
                if (letterChoice == upperAlphabet[k]) {
                    //upperAlphabet[k] = '*';
                    guessedLetters[k] = 1; //note which letter has been chosen
                }
            }
        } while (userChoiceString.length() != 1
                && userChoiceString.length() != wordtoGuess.length()
                || Character.isLetter(letterChoice) == false
                || guessed == true);

        if (userChoiceString.length() == 1) { // if input is only 1 character
            /*
            for (int k = 0; k < upperAlphabet.length; k++) { // A used letter is replaced by * in alphabet array.
                if (letterChoice == upperAlphabet[k]) {
                    //upperAlphabet[k] = '*';
                    guessedLetters[k] = 1;
                }
            }
            */

            for (int m = 0; m < wordtoGuess.length(); m++) { // If a letter is correct, reveal the correct letter in the word to guess.
                if (letterChoice == wordArray[m]) {
                    guessingWordArray[m] = wordArray[m];
                }
            }
            wordArraytoString = new String(guessingWordArray); // If all letters are revealed in the word to guess, display winning message when count of guesses.
            if (wordArraytoString.equals(wordtoGuess)) {

                System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
                System.out.print("Congratulations.");
                System.out.print("You guessed the word: ");
                System.out.print(wordtoGuess);
                System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guesses.");
                break;

            }

        } else if (userChoiceString.length() == wordtoGuess.length()) { // If user2 tries to guess the whole word, displays winning message and number of guesses
            if (userChoiceString.equals(wordtoGuess)) {
                System.out.println(guessingWordArray);
                System.out.print("Congratulations.");
                System.out.print("You guessed the word: ");
                System.out.print(wordtoGuess);
                if (j == 0)
                    System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guess.");
                else
                    System.out.println(" in " + (j + 1) + " guesses.");
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Wrong guess. Please try again."); // If guessing word is wrong.
        }

        if (j >= 9)
            System.out
                    .println("You did not guess the word in the number of attemps allowed. Better luck next time."); // If exceeds 10 tries.
    }

}

}
```